# If someone deletes their own post that has a 3+ positive 'score' will they lose that rep?

Tags: discussion

I know you can get a 'bronze badge' if you delete a +3 score post, but do you lose that rep?

Comment: I’m fairly sure the answer is “yes”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this question from Meta.StackExchange:

- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> Reputation changes from votes (both up and down) on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained).
>
> Reputation lost as a penalty for having a post deleted by flagging is not returned.

So the answer is "yes and no". If you erase your own question with at score of at least 3 (not necessarily 3 upvotes - could be 50 upvotes and 47 downvotes) that has been around for a while, you won't lose the rep.

Comment: As a side note: this (60 days) is a **new feature**. Back when I earned my bronze badge; you lost the rep 100% of time, even form an older post. And to delete a post, you had to find a terminal in another state, and walk there barefoot, in the snow, uphill both ways.

Comment: Thanks. I don't always get the opportunity to research as much as I'd like.